# 'char (*RtlpNumberOf(T (&)[N]))[N]': could not deduce template argument for 'T (&)[N]' from 'char *'

Tags: c++

I originally wrote this code, which combines 10 `const char[]`'s into one big `char[]`. It works fine.

```
char total[1000000];
memcpy(total, myData0, ARRAYSIZE(myData0));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0)], myData1, ARRAYSIZE(myData1));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0) + ARRAYSIZE(myData1)], myData2, ARRAYSIZE(myData2));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0) + ARRAYSIZE(myData1) + ARRAYSIZE(myData2)], myData3, ARRAYSIZE(myData3));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0) + ARRAYSIZE(myData1) + ARRAYSIZE(myData2) + ARRAYSIZE(myData3)], myData4, ARRAYSIZE(myData4));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0) + ARRAYSIZE(myData1) + ARRAYSIZE(myData2) + ARRAYSIZE(myData3) + ARRAYSIZE(myData4)], myData5, ARRAYSIZE(myData5));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0) + ARRAYSIZE(myData1) + ARRAYSIZE(myData2) + ARRAYSIZE(myData3) + ARRAYSIZE(myData4) + ARRAYSIZE(myData5)], myData6, ARRAYSIZE(myData6));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0) + ARRAYSIZE(myData1) + ARRAYSIZE(myData2) + ARRAYSIZE(myData3) + ARRAYSIZE(myData4) + ARRAYSIZE(myData5) + ARRAYSIZE(myData6)], myData7, ARRAYSIZE(myData7));
memcpy(&total[ARRAYSIZE(myData0) + ARRAYSIZE(myData1) + ARRAYSIZE(myData2) + ARRAYSIZE(myData3) + ARRAYSIZE(myData4) + ARRAYSIZE(myData5) + ARRAYSIZE(myData6) + ARRAYSIZE(myData7)], myData8, ARRAYSIZE(myData8));
```

But I figured I could clean it up significantly using an array and looping through.

```
char total[1000000];
char* myarray[10] = { myData0, myData1, myData2, myData3, myData4, myData5, myData6, myData7, myData8, myData9 };

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(myarray); i++)
{
    memcpy(total, &myarray[i], ARRAYSIZE(myarray[i]));
}
```

I thought I was doing alright, but this code does not compile. I get an error under `ARRAYSIZE(myarray[i])`, which reads `'char (*RtlpNumberOf(T (&)[N]))[N]': could not deduce template argument for 'T (&)[N]' from 'char *'`. I don't understand what the issue is here. I tried using `sizeof` alternatively, but it didn't copy correctly. Why am I not able to use ARRAYSIZE in this case?

Comment: You error seems to indicate that you have C++ code, but what I see appears to be C. Pick a language, C != C++.  Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: @jwdonahue Sorry, that was an accidental tagging on my part. It has been corrected

Comment: Ok, where is the definition of ARRAYSIZE?

Comment: ARRAYSIZE is a macro - (sizeof(*RtlpNumberOf(A)))

Comment: What's `RtlpNumberOf` then? In any case, just as the compiler told you, it is not possible to deduce the size of `myarray[i]` "sub-array" since it is not an array at all. It is a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first piece of code, you're calling `ARRAYSIZE` on actual arrays.  In the second, you're passing a `char *` to it instead.  This macro (actually, the `RtlpNumberOf` macro that underlies it) expects an array.  Arrays and pointers are not the same thing, and this is a perfect illustration of that.

Create a second array that has the sizes of the other arrays and use that when calling `memcpy`:

```
char total[1000000];
char* myarray[10] = { myData0, myData1, myData2, myData3, myData4, 
                      myData5, myData6, myData7, myData8, myData9 };
size_t myarray_sizes[10] = { ARRAYSIZE(myData0), ARRAYSIZE(myData1), ARRAYSIZE(myData2), 
                             ARRAYSIZE(myData3), ARRAYSIZE(myData4), ARRAYSIZE(myData5), 
                             ARRAYSIZE(myData6), ARRAYSIZE(myData7), ARRAYSIZE(myData8), 
                             ARRAYSIZE(myData9) };


for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(myarray); i++)
{
    memcpy(total, &myarray[i], myarray_sizes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or how about this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    char total[1000000];
    char * myData0 = "this ";
    char * myData1 = "is ";
    char * myData2 = "a ";
    char * myData3 = "test1 ";
    char * myData4 = "test2 ";
    char * myData5 = "test3 ";
    char * myData6 = "test4 ";
    char * myData7 = "test5 ";
    char * myData8 = "test6 ";
    char * myData9 = "test7 ";

    char* myarray[10] = { myData0, myData1, myData2, myData3, myData4, myData5, myData6, myData7, myData8, myData9 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        strcat(total, myarray[i]);
    }

    std::cout << total << std::endl;

}
```